# $f:Y\to X$ scheme morphism. $E\in QCoh(X),L$ line bundle over $Y$. If $f^\star(E)\to L$ surjective, then $f^\star(E)\to f^\star f_\star(L)$ surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:Y\to X$ be scheme morphism. $E\in QCoh(X)$. $L$ is line bundle over $Y$.

If $\phi: f^\star(E)\to L$ surjective, then $f^\star(E)\to f^\star f_\star(L)$ surjective.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why is $f^\star(E)\to f^\star f_\star(L)$ obviously surjection which is induced by adjoint functoriality? I consider $Hom(f^\star E,L)=Hom(E,f_\star(L))$. Then $\phi\to\phi':E\to f_\star(L)$. Then $f^\star(\phi'):f^\star(E)\to f^\star f_\star(L)$. Then the question is to ask whether stalkwise is surjection. However this is asking $E_x\to f_\star(L)_x$ epimorphism. Now $f^\star(E)\to L$ gives $E_x\to L_y$ surjection for any $y\to x$. In particular, $E_x\to f_\star(L)_x$ is epimorphism. I found my reasoning very convoluted somehow and it is ad hoc. Is there an easy way to see $f^\star(E)\to f^\star f_\star(L)$?

$\textbf{Q':}$ I want to write down when $Y=P^1_k$ and $X=Spec(k)$, $f^\star(O_X(1))\to k^2$ identity, the total map $f^\star(V)\to f^\star(f_\star O_X(1))\to O_X(1)$ concretely. Is there an easy way to write it down?

Comment: The statement is false in general. Consider $E=O_Y, L=O_X$ and $f$ a finite map of degree greater than one.

Comment: @Mohan So $L$ needs to be required to be $f$ very ample then? However, it seems that in Ueno's Algebraic Geometry 2 chpt 5 section on ampleness, this was demonstrated independent of ampleness unless I have misunderstood the book. The whole goal is to show $f^\star(E)\to f^\star f_\star(L)\to L$'s last map being surjection. Where do I need $L$ being $f$ very ampleness to support idea that $f^\star(E)\to f^\star f_\star(L)$ surjection? I guess I do not need $f^\star(E)\to f^\star f_\star(L)$ surjection to conclude surjectivity then.

Comment: No, ampleness has nothing to do with it. For a finite map of degree $d>1$, $f^*f_*L$ is a vector bundle of rank $d$. So, if you take $E$ to be a line bundle on $X$ and $L=f^*E$, you have a problem.